# Creating Suppression File from Existing Valgrind Report

Tags: c++, valgrind

The easiest way to create a valgrind report is to run the valgrind with the command `--gen-suppressions=all`.

But still we have to run the test atleast once. In my case a single valgrind test takes too long and since I already have a previously run valgrind report that was run without the `--gen-suppressions=all` command, is there a way to get the suppression commands from that report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, but it will be much easier if Valgrind does the generation for you. I would only suggest that you try this if you don't have too many suppressions to add.

The format is described [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress). It looks like this

```
{
    description, preferably unique
    Memcheck:[error type]
    callstack 1
    callstack 2
    etc
}
```

If you want to do this all by hand, you will need to work out all of the mappings from the verbose log descriptions to the terse suppression name. For instance

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

corresponds to

> Memcheck:Cond

Next for the callstack your life will be easier if you just have one application (no dynamic libraries) and it is compiled with debug info. You will need to work out

- the mangled name of the function using 'fun'
- if you don't have the function name, then the dynamic library using 'obj'
- if your exe is stripped then I think that you have to use the hex address

You may also want to use wildcards. '*' matches path components and ... matches anything in the depth of the callstack. For instance

fun:foo
   ...
   fun:bar

This will match any number of call levels between foo and bar.

Comment: in order to give the function name using `fun:`, one has to know the mangled name of the function. Is there an easier way to get the mangled name of the functions. The main reason to go for valgrind to auto generate the suppression file was not being able to get the correct mangled name for the function in the first place

Comment: Not really. You can use tools like nm to query the names in the exe or lib. If you use -C then it will display the undecorated name.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know about `nm`